# What is this container in the engine and should it be filled with water?

Tags: honda, maintenance, part-identification, water

The car is Honda Life 2007. While checking for water I wondered what this is and should it be filled with water/coolant?

I have attached the image of the engine with the container I am talking about marked in red.

[image: Engine]

*Plus if someone can point to the official manual of the car it will be very helpful.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking through manuals and pictures online (Japanese) and Google translate, it is a Coolant Water Reserve Tank.

[Link to the manual, page 349](http://www.honda.co.jp/ownersmanual/pdf/auto/life/30SFA630_web.pdf?genpo=HondaMotor&model=LIFE)